# ^M in the diff using svn

Tags: svn, newline

I am getting ^M character at the end of each line in the diff which I took recently. But When I check the source code, I did not find any such character.

Although I got rid of it using :%s/^M//g in the generated diff file, I still wonder how it appeared in the diff file and also want to know if any issues that may arise later when I check in the file.

Thank you

Comment: [Ivan Jovovic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28110563/368630) has the answer, but you can do `svn diff -x --ignore-eol-style` to ignore these EOL issues. See `svn help diff` for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Windows stores an end-of-line as - 0x0D0A (carriage return + line feed). Unix use 0x0A (a line feed). The **^M** is a visual representation of 0x0D (a carriage return).

As [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.file-portability.html) says:

> The solution to this problem is the svn:eol-style property. When this
>   property is set to a valid value, Subversion uses it to determine what
>   special processing to perform on the file so that the file's
>   line-ending style isn't flip-flopping with every commit that comes
>   from a different operating system. The valid values are:
>
> native This causes the file to contain the EOL markers that are native
>   to the operating system on which Subversion was run. In other words,
>   if a user on a Windows machine checks out a working copy that contains
>   a file with an svn:eol-style property set to native, that file will
>   contain CRLF EOL markers. A Unix user checking out a working copy that
>   contains the same file will see LF EOL markers in his copy of the
>   file.
>
> Note that Subversion will actually store the file in the repository
>   using normalized LF EOL markers regardless of the operating system.
>   This is basically transparent to the user, though.

This is a quick fix:

```
svn propset svn:eol-style native filename
svn commit filename
```

And [setting automatic property](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/the-road-to-repository-dictated-configuration-day-2-autoprops) is long-term solution.